# Rail Active admin and BCrypt Gem, how to decrypt a password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using rails active admin gem and BCrypt Gem. Now I want to decrypt all users password.How can I do this?

Thanks your support!!

Comment: I don't think you can. And that's why we use `bcrypt`.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. That is a existing project. They using active admin gem and BCrypt Gem. I want to decrypt all users password. Thank you..

Comment: That's what I'm saying. You **CAN'T** do that. `bcrypt` was designed in order to avoid someone to get password from a database even if the database was compromised.

Comment: @RaguNatarajan Why do you want to decrypt the passwords ?

Comment: @AshishGaur. That is a existing project. I want to develop in PHP. So  I want to decrypt all users password or I want use Bcrypt in PHP.

Comment: @lcguida. Can I use the same Bcrypt in PHP

Comment: Yes if the PHP application uses the same encryption mechanism then you can.

Comment: I think Bcrypt is made for one-way cryptography. A hashing function. So you can't decrypt passowords. Think about this: **If it were easy for someone to decrypt password, how safe would your data be? If you can decrypt, anybody can do the same, including hackers!**. Read this: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand from your comments you want to migrate an existing app in PHP to Rails.
**You cannot decrypt the password and get the plain text.**

So you need to first find out the encryption mechanism used in the PHP app. If you can't find that out from your codebase then you can follow these steps:

1. Create a user from your PHP app. Set the password as `test`.
2. Get the encrypted password from the database.
3. Go to [BCrypt Calculator](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator) and check if `test` matches the encrypted password.
4. If it matches then your PHP app is using BCrypt and moving over to Rails using BCrypt will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, because [`bcrypt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) is a password hashing function, not an encryption.

That is the whole point of using `bcrypt`.

Comment: Thanks.. Can I use the same Bcrypt in PHP??